# To subtract a text from the last value

Tags: awk

I have a text file like below. I want the check the type of file based on the extension and perform the action.

```
Example.2019.txt
Example.test.2019.txt
Example.test.2019.txt.gz
Example.test.2019.txt.Z
```

I used `cut -d'.' - f3` for the first record format. It works. But it is not working when it is for the others. Also tried the below `awk` command as well.

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $(NF-sub(/..+$/,"",$1)1}'
```

to get the first appearance of dot from last field and print the value but I think I made some syntax error and is not working.

Comment: What is your expected output? What actions do you want to do depending on the extension?

Comment: Multiple answers on extracting the extension from a filename: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Comment: Thanks for sharing the old post. I got the required information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        *.txt)
            some_txt_action
            ;;
        *.gz)
            some_gz_action
            ;;
        *.Z)
            some_Z_action
            ;;
        *)
            echo 'Did not match a pattern'
    esac
done <filelist
```

Or, for a bit more precise matching of filename suffixes,

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        *.txt)
            some_txt_action
            ;;
        *.txt.gz)
            some_txtgz_action
            ;;
        *.txt.Z)
            some_txtZ_action
            ;;
        *)
            echo 'Did not match a pattern'
    esac
done <filelist
```

Both of the above loops would read lines of text from the file `filelist`.  It will then perform actions based on the end of the line read from the file.

The `some_XXX_action` in the code are placeholders that you are expected to replace with the actual actions to take when encountering a line of text that matches that particular pattern.